# Pivot Table without an aggregate

Tags: sql, pivot

Data set

```
|ID |   PCC     |SpecialtyID    |   Tier      |
|---|-----------|---------------|-------------|
|1  |   1       |   5           |   1         |
|1  |   6       |   5           |   3         |
|1  |   NULL    |   5           |   2         |
|2  |   NULL    |   5           |   3         |
|2  |   6       |   5           |   1         |
|3  |   6       |   5           |   3         |
|3  |   1       |   5           |   2         |
|4  |   NULL    |   5           |   2         |
```

Desired result

```
|ID |SpecialtyID    |TierPCCNull| TierPCC1  |TierPCC6
|---|---------------|-----------|-----------|----------
|1  |   5           |   2       |   1       |3
|2  |   5           |   3       |   3       |1
|3  |   5           |   2       |   2       |3
|4  |   5           |   2       |   2       |2
```

PCC 1 and 6 should always have a tier value whether they truly exist or not. I've tried to pivot but I'm not getting the result set I want. There are 3 tiers (1,2,3) and 3 PCC (1,6,NULL) values.
This is the logic for the tiers:
If only one PCC value exists, the tier of PCC Null becomes the tier of the missing PCC.
If only PCC Null exists, the Null tier value becomes the tier value of both PCc 1 and 6.

---

Used the coalesce suggestion and I've almost got what I needed!
There should be 1 row per ID.
[image]

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to default to the `NULL` value if the stated value isn't available.

You can use conditional aggregation and `coalesce()`:

```
select id, specialtyid,
       max(case when pcc is null then tier end) as TierPCCNull,
       coalesce( max(case when pcc = 1 then tier end),
                 max(case when pcc is null then tier end)
               ) as TierPCC1,
       coalesce( max(case when pcc = 6 then tier end),
                 max(case when pcc is null then tier end)
               ) as TierPCC6                 
from t
group by id, specialtyid;
```